Checkbox selection not being selective
I am playing around with WPF and powershell project for a tool and some learning. I have built a screen which allows you to display user information. I have added checkboxes next to each textbox so that if you edit a field then click the button it will change that section.
The issue i have is i cannot get it to work based on the selection. I have the below which works in the way it changes all fields regardless of the selection. I have played around with a few combinations but none seem to give the desired effect.
function UpdateUserInfoClick
{
    param($sender, $e)

# prepare table
$userUpdateData = @{
  Identity = $UserSearchName.text
  Server   = $UserSearchDomainSelect.text
  Credential = $ADMCreds
  GivenName = $USFN.Text
  SurName = $USLN.Text
  DisplayName = $USDN.Text
  Description = $USDesc.Text
  Confirm = $false

}

# populate entry values associated with checked checkboxes
if ($USFNCB.IsChecked = $true) {
  $userUpdateData['GivenName'] = $USFN.Text
}
if ($USLNCB.IsChecked = $true) {
  $userUpdateData['SurName'] = $USLN.Text
}
if ($USDNCB.IsChecked = $true) {
  $userUpdateData['DisplayName'] = $USDN.Text
}
if ($USDescCB.IsChecked = $true) {
  $userUpdateData['Description'] = $USDesc.Text
}
# decide on target server based on selected domain
if ($UserSearchDomainSelect.text -eq "Domain1") {
  $userUpdateData['Server'] = 'Domain1.com'
}
elseif ($UserSearchDomainSelect.text -eq "Domain2") {
  $userUpdateData['Server'] = 'Domain2.com'
}
elseif ($UserSearchDomainSelect.text -eq "Domain3.com") {
  $userUpdateData['Server'] = 'Domain3.com'
}
else {
  throw 'unexpected domain selection, cannot map to domain controller'
}
if ($userUpdateData.Count -gt 1) {
  # at least 1 updated property was checked, let's update the backend
  Set-ADUser @userUpdateData
}

}

The xaml code for one of the checkboxes
<CheckBox x:Name="USFNCB" Content="" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="461,148,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="20" Width="20" IsChecked="False"/>

Not sure if there is some more definition need for the states in the Xaml or the the set-eventhandlers?
Thanks

= is only for assignment, you want if ($USFNCB.IsChecked) {...} (or if ($USFNCB.IsChecked -eq $true) {...})

@MathiasR.Jessen Thank you adding the -eq and it work fine. If you add it as an answer. I will mark it as such for you. Thank you.

In PowerShell, = is never used as a comparison operator - it's only used for assignment.
Like in most other C-inspired languages, referencing an assignment operation as a value expression evaluates to a reference to the assignment target, which after the assignment contains the value $true.
In plain English, that means that this:
if ($USFNCB.IsChecked = $true) {
  $userUpdateData['GivenName'] = $USFN.Text
}

... is equivalent to
if ($true) {
  $userUpdateData['GivenName'] = $USFN.Text
}

Remove the assignment operation and your if statements will be evaluated as you expect them to:
function UpdateUserInfoClick {
  param($sender, $e)

  # prepare table
  $userUpdateData = @{
    Identity    = $UserSearchName.text
    Server      = $UserSearchDomainSelect.text
    Credential  = $ADMCreds
    GivenName   = $USFN.Text
    SurName     = $USLN.Text
    DisplayName = $USDN.Text
    Description = $USDesc.Text
    Confirm     = $false
  }

  # populate entry values associated with checked checkboxes
  if ($USFNCB.IsChecked) {
    $userUpdateData['GivenName'] = $USFN.Text
  }
  if ($USLNCB.IsChecked) {
    $userUpdateData['SurName'] = $USLN.Text
  }
  if ($USDNCB.IsChecked) {
    $userUpdateData['DisplayName'] = $USDN.Text
  }
  if ($USDescCB.IsChecked) {
    $userUpdateData['Description'] = $USDesc.Text
  }

  # decide on target server based on selected domain
  if ($UserSearchDomainSelect.Text -in "Domain1","Domain2","Domain3") {
    $userUpdateData['Server'] = $UserSearchDomainSelect.Text
  }
  else {
    throw 'unexpected domain selection, cannot map to domain controller'
  }

  if ($userUpdateData.Count -gt 1) {
    # at least 1 updated property was checked, let's update the backend
    Set-ADUser @userUpdateData
  }
}

